# Spring boot graphql-java, subscriptions and streamlisteners

Tags: rx-java, observable, spring-cloud-stream, graphql-java, graphql-subscriptions

I'm trying to create an observable from a streamlistener response but are unable to do so. I'm quite new to the idea of EventObservable and Reactive Java. It would be helpful if someone could look into my code to see if it has been constructed the right way and if my understanding of the concept is on the right path.

```
@Component
public class EventObservable {

private Observable<Event> observable = new Observable<Event>() {
    @Override
    protected void subscribeActual(Observer<? super Event> observer) {
        return;
    }
};

public Observable<Event> getObservable () {
    return this.observable;
}
}

@EnableBinding(ConsumerChannels.class)
public class EventConsumer {

@Autowired
private EventObservable eventObservable;

@StreamListener(ConsumerChannels.EVENT_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL)
public void fetchEvent(Message asd){
    Event event = new Event("123123","google.io","This is an event","Singapore");
    eventObservable.getObservable().just(event);
    return;
}
}

@Component
public class SubscriptionGraphQlUtilities {

private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SubscriptionGraphQlUtilities.class);

@Value("classpath:schemas.graphqls")
private Resource schemaResource;

private final static EventPublisher EVENT_PUBLISHER = new EventPublisher();

private final GraphQLSchema graphQLSchema;

public SubscriptionGraphQlUtilities(){
    graphQLSchema = buildSchema();
}

private GraphQLSchema buildSchema() {
    //
    // reads a file that provides the schema types
    //
    Reader streamReader = loadSchemaFile("schemas.graphqls");
    TypeDefinitionRegistry typeRegistry = new SchemaParser().parse(streamReader);

    RuntimeWiring wiring = RuntimeWiring.newRuntimeWiring()
            .type(newTypeWiring("subscription")
                    .dataFetcher("subscribeEvent", getEventsDataFetcher())
            )
            .build();

    return new SchemaGenerator().makeExecutableSchema(typeRegistry, wiring);
}

private DataFetcher getEventsDataFetcher(){
    return environment -> {
        return EVENT_PUBLISHER.getPublisher();
    };
}

public GraphQLSchema getGraphQLSchema() {
    return graphQLSchema;
}

@SuppressWarnings("SameParameterValue")
private Reader loadSchemaFile(String name) {
    InputStream stream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(name);
    return new InputStreamReader(stream);
}
}

@EnableBinding(ConsumerChannels.class)
public class SubscriptionConsumer {

private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SubscriptionConsumer.class);

private final AtomicReference<Subscription> subscriptionRef = new AtomicReference<>();
private final SubscriptionGraphQlUtilities graphQlUtilities = new SubscriptionGraphQlUtilities();

Instrumentation instrumentation = new ChainedInstrumentation(
        Collections.singletonList(new TracingInstrumentation())
);

@StreamListener(ConsumerChannels.QUERY_INPUT)
public void fetchSubscription(Message asd){
    logger.info("Received subscription query:{}",asd.toString());
    try {
        String query = "subscription{subscribeEvent{name}}";
        String query2 = "subscription {\n    subscribeEvent{\n\t\tid\n        name\n\t\tdescription\n\t\tlocation\n\t}\n}";

        GraphQL graphQL = GraphQL
                .newGraphQL(graphQlUtilities.getGraphQLSchema())
                .instrumentation(instrumentation)
                .build();

        ExecutionResult executionResult = graphQL.execute(query2);

        Publisher<ExecutionResult> eventStream = executionResult.getData();
        eventStream.subscribe(new Subscriber<ExecutionResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Subscription subscription) {
                logger.info("Successfully subscribed");
                subscriptionRef.set(subscription);
                request(1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(ExecutionResult executionResult) {
                logger.info("Sending event updates");
                Object result = executionResult.getData();
                logger.info("This is the event,{}", result);
                request(1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                logger.error("Subscription threw an exception", throwable);
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                logger.info("Subscription complete");
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return;
}

private void request(int n) {
    Subscription subscription = subscriptionRef.get();
    if (subscription != null) {
        subscription.request(n);
    }
}
}
```